# Web API with Knockout.js - Why isn't this working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, knockout.js

I have a web API which successfully returns an array of blog posts in JSON format:

```
[{"ID":1,"Title":"First Blog Post","Body":"Some Content"},{"ID":2,"Title":"Second BlogPost","Body":"Some other content"}]
```

For exercise purposes, I want to display all posts in a list using Knockout.js.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    function AppViewModel() {
        var self = this;

        self.posts = ko.observableArray([
        { Title: 'Default Title', Body: 'Default Body' },
        ]);

        $.getJSON('api/posts', function (data) {
            ko.mapping.fromJSON(data, {}, self.posts);
        });

    }

    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());

});
```

My bindings:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: posts">
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: Title"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: Body"></td>
                </tr>
</tbody>
```

My table shows up empty, it's not showing the JSON data for some reason...

**ANSWER:** I had to change fromJSON to fromJS and it works! Thanks so much for your help everyone

Comment: `mapping` is a part of the [Knockout Mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html). Have you referenced the `knockout.mapping.js` in your view?

Comment: Hmm, there was a mistake in the way I had referenced the mapping.js file, which I now fixed.

The error is now gone, but my html table with bindings is empty, instead of showing the posts.

Comment: You can edit your question with the new informations. And just a guess change `ko.mapping.fromJS(data, self.posts);` to `ko.mapping.fromJSON (data, self.posts);`

Comment: Can you post your template the html table with the bindings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you need to specify the update target for the mapping.

From the [Knockout Mapping plugin documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html):

> If, like in the example above, you are performing the mapping inside
>   of a class, you would like to have this as the target of your mapping
>   operation. The third parameter to ko.mapping.fromJS indicates the
>   target. For example,

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, someObject);
```

So in your case:

```
$.getJSON('api/posts', function (data) {
        ko.mapping.fromJSON(data, {}, self.posts);
    });
```

A working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gFVwR/1/)

Also note that that the **property names are case sensitive** and they should match in the JSON and in your viewmodel and bindings. e.g you retrive `"Title"` but you are using `title`

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work in your JSFiddle example.
I have updated my code (see original post) as per your tips, but my table now appears empty after the JSON is loaded.

Comment: Thanks, your fix worked when I changed 'fromJSON' to 'fromJS'

Answer (score 0):

The json being returned has title case property names, but the original in self.posts has lowercase property names.  I assume you are binding to the lowercase version in your template. Consider changing the json returned to lowercase too.